# Unable to make an iterable decimal function in Python

Tags: python, iteration, sum

I want to calculate the sum of

```
1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/30
```

I run the code unsuccessfully

```
import decimal
import math
var=decimal.Decimal(1/i)

for i in range(1,31):
   print(sum(var))
```

I get the error

```
'Decimal' object is not iterable
```

**How can you make the iterable function in Python?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
print(sum(decimal.Decimal(1) / i for i in range(1, 31)))
```

The reason your code doesn't work, is that you try to iterate over *one* `Decimal` instance (through the use of `sum`). Furthermore, your definition of `var` is invalid. Your intention was probably something like this:

```
var = lambda i: decimal.Decimal(str(1.0 / i))
```

(Note the use of `str`, `Decimal` [does not permit](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/decimal.html) a floating point argument). But even then your loop would not work, because the use of `sum` *inside* the loop is inherently flawed. `sum` should be used *after* the loop has created all fractions that you want to sum. So that would be either of:

```
print(sum(var(i) for i in range(1,31)))
print(sum(map(var, range(1, 31))))
```

For completeness, yet another way to do this is the following:

```
one = decimal.Decimal(1)
unitFractions = (one / i for i in itertools.count(1))
print(sum(itertools.islice(unitFractions, 30)))
```

However, as mentioned by [gs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845787/unable-to-make-an-iterable-decimal-function-in-python/845826#845826), the [fractions](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) provides an alternative method that yields a fractional answer:

```
>>> unitFractions = (fractions.Fraction(1, i) for i in itertools.count(1))
>>> print(sum(itertools.islice(unitFractions, 30)))
9304682830147/2329089562800
```

Answer (score 3):

You write:

```
var=decimal.Decimal(1/i)
```

which is weird since 'i' is not defined at that point.  How about:

```
one = decimal.Decimal( "1" )
total = decimal.Decimal( "0" )
for i in range( 1, 31 ):
    total += one / decimal.Decimal( "%d" % i )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is, that `decimal.Decimal(4)` isn't a function, but an object.

---

BTW: It looks like the [Fractions](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) (Python 2.6) module is what you really need.

Comment: I agree about Fraction. Decimal is just supposed to represent finite base-10 decimals. It won't represent stuff like 1/3 precisely. So why use it? Fraction is what you want to do arithmetic with fractions.